# Directly changing text displayed by JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, settext

I have got a JTextField active which is kind of my programs console. Whenever something happens I just display a text so the users know what's going on.

It works fine except for when I try to let some function edit the text directly.
A perfect example is my checkJob-method:

```
public void checkJob(int pos){
    if(locked == false){
        if(active[pos] == true){
            textArea.setText(undoJob(pos));
        }else{
            textArea.setText(setJob(pos));
        }
    }else{
        String oldText = textArea.getText();
        textArea.setText("Das Spiel hat bereits begonnen.");
        textArea.setText(countDown(oldText));
    }

}
public String countDown(String oldText){
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+5000;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (currentTime < endTime){
        if(currentTime >= startTime+1000){
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            startTime = startTime+1000;
        }else{
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    return oldText;
}
```

As you can see, once locked is true it should save the text that is currently in the field as a String-variable called oldText, set the textArea to "Das Spiel hat bereits begonnen." and after the countDown-method has finished, set the textArea back to old Text. Sadly, it only works for the second time, not when I try to directly change the textArea.

Note: 
It always sets the text if I use:

```
textArea.setText(method());
```

so the method returns a String to be displayed, but it doesn't work for:

```
textArea.setText("Text");
```

I tried to turn some properties around, even replace my JTextField with a JPane and JTextArea but it still has the same problem. Will the textArea need to 'update' itself after I set a text directly?

Comment: I just noticed something interesting: The text is actually in the textArea. I added some System.out.println(textArea.getText()); and it does spit out the correct text. So this problem seems to be a bug where stuff just doesn't show up.

Comment: Note:  Java and Javascript are entirely separate languages.